# Why do we store X_test to y_preds variable in Scikit learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am currently working on a Machine Learning project with no prior hands-on experience of Machine Learning or Python. I have just encountered the following code online, but don't know why is that actually happening.

1. Where is the trained data stored? is it stored in X_train or X_test?
2. Why did we predict X_test and stored it to y_preds variable? Since we used y_preds, I was expecting  something like this:

   ```
   y_preds = clf.predict(y_test)
   ```

**Code:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# Using train_test_split() function, defining test data size + storing it to variables of test, train 
  and split data

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


# Fitting the data into the training model defined above

clf.fit(X_train, y_train);

# Making predictions on our trained data

y_preds = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: predict takes the inputs (X) through the model to produce outputs (y), it makes no sense to feed outputs as inputs to a model.

Comment: Well, if that is the case. Getting inputs from X to product outputs for Y also doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Then I think you should read more about machine learning models, this site is not meant to teach you about machine learning and how it works. This is a programming site.

Comment: That is what I have said right in the start of my question, that I am new to Machine Learning. Also, I am not asking for your help if you are not willing to. There are still thousands of people around there to offer it to newbies.

Comment: Its not me, its the rules, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/do-pure-machine-learning-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a learning problem considers a set of n samples of data and then tries to predict properties of unknown data. If each sample is more than a single number and, for instance, a multi-dimensional entry (aka multivariate data), it is said to have several attributes or features.

Learning problems fall into a few categories:

A) supervised learning, in which the data comes with additional attributes that we want to predict (Click here to go to the scikit-learn supervised learning page).This problem can be either:

1. classification: samples belong to two or more classes and we want to learn from already labeled data how to predict the class of unlabeled data. An example of a classification problem would be handwritten digit recognition, in which the aim is to assign each input vector to one of a finite number of discrete categories. Another way to think of classification is as a discrete (as opposed to continuous) form of supervised learning where one has a limited number of categories and for each of the n samples provided, one is to try to label them with the correct category or class.
2. regression: if the desired output consists of one or more continuous variables, then the task is called regression. An example of a regression problem would be the prediction of the length of a salmon as a function of its age and weight.

B) unsupervised learning, in which the training data consists of a set of input vectors x without any corresponding target values. The goal in such problems may be to discover groups of similar examples within the data, where it is called clustering, or to determine the distribution of data within the input space, known as density estimation, or to project the data from a high-dimensional space down to two or three dimensions for the purpose of visualization (Click here to go to the Scikit-Learn unsupervised learning page).

Basically, machine learning is about learning some properties of a data set and then testing those properties against another data set. A common practice in machine learning is to evaluate an algorithm by splitting a data set into two. We call one of those sets the training set, on which we learn some properties; we call the other set the testing set, on which we test the learned properties.

Take a look at the link below.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html

That is an excellent resource for learning all about Scikit Learn.  It's hard to get your mind around some of these things, but it's a great learning experience, and it really does work!